# Instagram tag endpoint not returning public photo

Tags: php, api, instagram

I'm coding an app that should return the latest photos from an hashtag with php. The problem is that the app only returns photos I've uploaded. Is it normal? Thank you in advance!

Comment: show your code and a link to the instagram developer where it should do something else

Answer (score 2):

I think you are in Sandbox mode, so it will only show photos that are in your Sandbox user list (which is just you, I guess)
Once your app is reviewed and approved, all users will show up.

Here are more details:
https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

> To help you develop and test your app, the users and media available
>   in Sandbox mode are real Instagram data (i.e. what is normally visible
>   in the Instagram app), but with the following conditions:
>
> - Apps in sandbox are restricted to 10 users
> - Data is restricted to the 10 users and the 20 most recent media from each of those users